# java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed **ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy certificate**

Tags: jmeter, ssl-certificate

I am using `Jmeter 5.4.1` with `Java 1_8_301` and `Firefox 91.0`. 
I have imported the `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA` into Firefox browser and this certificate is generated today and valid.

I have set up proxy settings in my Firefox browser. This testing is done on Windows and my web application uses a client certificate which I converted through `keytool`  into `PKCS12` format and added the following to the `system.properties` under `Jmeter-Home\bin`

My web app is loading fine without proxy but when I try to record getting the below error.

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed **ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy certificate**
```

I am not sure what I am missing here. I have been through all solutions mentioned in this regard and I am exhausted all my options now. I have been successful in recording using BlazeMeter but my company is not allowing me to use the Chrome extension for security reasons.

*Note:*

> Also, I forgot to add that the Jmeter recording working fine before. Started noticing issues after our java
> is upgraded from jdk_1.8.291 to jdk_1.8.301. I checked the difference
> between the two and both support TLS1.2 which is what our app uses and tried
> to downgrade to v291 didn't work either.

*Log:* 
Problem with SSL certificate for URL for 'XXXXX'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: `java.net.SocketException`: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to say what's wrong without seeing your [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) with debug logging enabled for the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

I can think of 2 options:

1. Double check the way you're importing the certificate into your browser, i.e. try recording a website with HTTPS without client certificate, i.e. https://example.com. If it fails - you will need to properly install the JMeter's certificate prior to proceeding with your application recording
2. If it will be successful for other HTTPS website but not for the particular your application most probably you need to import your client certificate into Firefox browser as well

As the last resort you can inspect the requests using [Firefox "network" tab](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor/request_list) and generate relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers manually. There is also [BlazeMeter JMX Converter service](https://converter.blazemeter.com/) which can transform HAR files into .JMX scripts but I think the same security restrictions will apply.

Comment: Thanks Dimitri for the reply. To answer your 2nd point above, I have imported the client cert into Firefox browser and able to access the application without proxy.  The problem is when using Jmeter to record. Here is the log file from one of the recordings:

Comment: 2021-08-24 15:13:44,664 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.'
2021-08-24 15:13:44,664 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.'
2021-08-24 15:13:44,933 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Valid alias found for :root_ca:
2021-08-24 15:13:44,933 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Valid alias found for :intermediate_ca:
2021-08-24 15:13:44,940 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: Creating Daemon Socket on port: 8181

Comment: 2021-08-24 15:13:44,944 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: Test Script Recorder up and running!
2021-08-24 15:17:31,407 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: Proxy will remove the headers: If-Modified-Since,If-None-Match,Host
2021-08-24 15:17:31,429 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [51448]  KeyStore for SSL loaded OK and put host 'content-signature-2.cdn.mozilla.net' in map with key (content-signature-2.cdn.mozilla.net)
2021-08-24 15:17:31,439 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPHC4Impl: HTTP request retry count = 0

Comment: 2021-08-24 15:17:31,444 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [51448]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'content-signature-2.cdn.mozilla.net'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
2021-08-24 15:17:31,446 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2021-08-24 15:17:31,812 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [51452]  KeyStore for SSL loaded OK and put host 'firefox.settings.services.mozilla.com' in map with key (firefox.settings.services.mozilla.com)

Comment: 2021-08-24 15:17:31,884 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [51453]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'firefox.settings.services.mozilla.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: readHandshakeRecord
2021-08-24 15:17:31,962 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [51460]  KeyStore for SSL loaded OK and put host 'push.services.mozilla.com' in map with key (push.services.mozilla.com)
2021-08-24 15:17:31,989 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.h.LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory: Setting up HTTPS TrustAll Socket Factory
2021-08-24 15:17:31,992 INFO o.a.j.u.JsseSSLManager: Using default SSL protocol: TLS

Comment: 2021-08-24 15:17:31,992 INFO o.a.j.u.JsseSSLManager: SSL session context: per-thread
2021-08-24 15:17:32,038 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: JmeterKeyStore Location: Auto_Testing.pfx type pkcs12
2021-08-24 15:17:32,039 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: KeyStore created OK
2021-08-24 15:17:32,040 WARN o.a.j.u.SSLManager: No password provided, and no GUI present so cannot prompt
2021-08-24 15:17:32,059 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Total of 1 aliases loaded OK from keystore Auto_Testing.pfx

Comment: 2021-08-24 15:17:32,059 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: TrustStore Location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\security\cacerts
2021-08-24 15:17:32,060 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: TrustStore created OK, Type: JKS
2021-08-24 15:17:32,062 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Truststore loaded OK from file
2021-08-24 15:17:32,297 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Add sample log-4 into controller log
2021-08-24 15:17:32,411 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [51463]  KeyStore for SSL loaded OK and put host 'safebrowsing.googleapis.com' in map with key (safebrowsing.googleapis.com)

Comment: 2021-08-24 15:17:38,659 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [51476]  KeyStore for SSL loaded OK and put host 'qa.fgsdev.com' in map with key (qa.fgsdev.com)
2021-08-24 15:17:39,302 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [51478]  KeyStore for SSL loaded OK and put host 'gxisaccess.gxaws.com' in map with key (gxisaccess.gxaws.com)
2021-08-24 15:17:39,326 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Add sample log-8 into controller log
2021-08-24 15:17:40,877 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [51480]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'gxisaccess.gxaws.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: readHandshakeRecord